# Need more comments on Function Closures of Go

Tags: function, go, closures

Below is the code of **Function Closures** in **A Tour of Go**, I know a little about function closures but I am a beginner for Go.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func adder() func(int) int {
    sum := 0
    return func(x int) int {
        sum += x
        return sum
    }
}

func main() {
    pos, neg := adder(), adder()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(
            pos(i),
            neg(-2*i),
        )
    }
}
```

Here are questions:

1. for `func adder() func(int) int {` what are *[parameter list]*  and *[return_types]* respectively?
2. for the same line with Question.1, why there is *(int)*, instead of something like *(x int)*?
3. for `pos, neg := adder(), adder()`, does it mean to assign the function *adder* to *pos* and *neg*, why not it should be `pos, neg := adder, adder`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q: for `func adder() func(int) int {` what are [parameter list] and [return_types] respectively?**

A: Here, we have a function called `adder()` that takes no arguments that returns a function `func(int) int` which takes an integer and returns an integer.

**Q: for the same line with Question.1, why there is `(int)`, instead of something like `(x int)`?**

A: This is the `adder()` function

```golang
func adder() func(int) int {
    sum := 0
    return func(x int) int {
        sum += x
        return sum
    }
}
```

Take a look at the function that is being returned, here `func(x int) int` already has a named parameter (`x`), so we don't need to mention it again at `func adder() func(int) int`, because if we'd do something like `func adder() func(x int) int`, the `x` here has no use.

So if the function that is being returned had, say, 2 parameters (one extra is a `string` type), then it would look like the following code:

```golang
func adder() func(int, string) int {
    sum := 0
    return func(x int, y string) int {
        sum += x
        fmt.Println(y)
        return sum
    }
}
```

Notice that we added a `string` type at `func adder() func(int, string) int {`, that's because the function we are returning takes a `string` type.

**Q: for pos, neg := adder(), adder(), does it mean to assign the function adder to pos and neg, why not it should be pos, neg := adder, adder?**

A: See, when we assign `pos` to `adder()` (`pos := adder()`), `pos` becomes a new function, because `adder()` returned a function `func(int) int`, thus we can do `pos(i)`.

Same goes for `neg`.